# Build multiple build variants in Microsoft AppCenter

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

I want to find out if any one has been able to build all the build variants of an Android application on Microsoft App Center?

When setting up the build process on App Center, you can only select one build type?

Comment: This feature is not yet supported. Follow feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/1929

Answer (score 5):

The only way around this was to create a new "App" in appcenter, but select the other build variants. Just needed to name the application appropriately.

I would suggest turning off build on push/commit as this will eat through your build time and only build manually as you need the other build variants to be tested

Comment: Another solution could be to have multiple 'copies' of the same branch,whereby there is some automated way of ensuring branches are always in the same state.

Comment: I have created multiple application on the AppCenter but how can I select different variants for each application on AppCenter ?

Comment: i havnt worked on AppCenter in YEARS but from what i can remember is that when you setting up the build, you are able to select the build variant for the build. You will then make your changes as so.

Example: Debug build, you will select the debug build variant and in your release build you will select your release build variant

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Create different branches for your environments. Let's say you have `staging` branch for instance.
2. Next, you add a GitHub action to sync `staging` with `master`. You can make use of this [GitHub Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/sync-branches) to do that easily.
3. Finally configure the `staging` branch on AppCenter with different config as you wish.

AppCenter is also tracking this feature request [here](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/50). Hopefully this will be available soon.